# UINavigationController's back button is translated for certain languages but not another?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, translation

I am using the default back button for UINavigationController (not setting any hardcoded text anywhere). My app is available in multiple languages. I noticed that the Back button gets translated in certain languages and not others.

For example, if I switch to French then I see "Retour" which is the correct translation for back. But if I switch to Bulgarian, then the button says "Back". Does Apple only provide OOTB support for certain languages and not others? Where can I find this list, if it actually exists?

Comment: You could just google on Bing: "iOS supported languages" - it brings up for instance: http://www.ibabbleon.com/iOS-Language-Codes-ISO-639.html

Comment: @Krumelur, thanks a lot. Do you want to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling for "iOS supported languages" brought up this:

ibabbleon.com/iOS-Language-Codes-ISO-639.html

> iOS supports 31 languages now, but only 21 languages are supported in
>   iTunes Connect. That means your app can be localized into some
>   languages, like Polish, but the app descriptions cannot.

Bulgarian is not included in this list. iOS will fall back to a default, which seems to be English in this case.

Apple also has [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html) about localising your apps.